# Split HDMI Image to 3D Projector System

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi, projector

I am quite stuck on a board, or something that could fit my needs.

I made a dual Projector 3D System at home, like this : http://www.cinema3dglass.com/Dual_projector_3D_polarization_system.php

And the HDMI can have different (8) formats(Left Right, Above Below, ect..) all here: https://www.tridef.com/user-guide/3d-file-formats

So the needed images on the incoming HDMI port can ble placed like above, and I need to split them on two separate HDMI outputs according to the format, so I can plug them into the projectors.
Basically I need a device that is in the first image in the first link above title: "HDMI Distribution Amplifier & EDID Emulator"

I know an *Arduino* can't handle this amount of processing, because I overloaded it with simlier tasks.
Can anyone Help me where to start? I foud *Panda* development board but that's too expensive.
Or if there is a not owerly expensive device existing for this task, I could buy that.
I manadged to use the system from Tridef 3D but that's hard to get working.

I'd like my device to get the input from a Chromecast 2.0, but if it's not possible a normal player 'll do it.

I found some devices called *HDMI Demultiplexer* they simply cut one half of the input, but that's quite expensieve, for 260$ and two would be needed.
Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What resolution and framerate is in the source? That will give you approximate frequencies to handle. As usually people do not know the terminology Arduino is not MCU nor CPU it is just abstraction. But youre right standard MCU's will most likelly not suffice for this. For example I was able to squeeze AT32 UC3A3256 to create 640x480 60Hz VGA color signal with heavy use of its HW peripherials build into it. But I think you want bigger resolutions + handling HDMI that is most likelly too much for MCU. Try find HDMI receiver/transmitter IC and use that. If none found there is also FPGA out there

Comment: After minute of google search I found this http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-4896960444351380765 so try to found a SDK kit for SIL9134 + SIL9135 with some fast processor (more likely FPGA) and enough RAM to receive/split/send frames and copy audio data if used

Comment: Wow Thank you! It helped me a lot. It seems quite advanced, but I'm impressed. 
A normal HD HDMI Stream is 1920*1080, but depending on the 3D format, a normal 3D stream is 3840*1080. So I need a horsekick of processing power.

Comment: or just FPGA based signal resequencers with some FIFO memory for each stream... (without any processor). But I think this question will be better for some audio/video and or HW/electric engineering site then in the raw programming site like this one.

Comment: If I am calculating right you got `1920*1080*60Hz ->  ~248.8MHz` pixel clock which on `10` bit signal is `3 * 2.488GHz` but I do not know the `HDMI` background looks like it has more channels so it is probably a fraction of this +/- some syncs ... That is too much for any CPU/MCU so FPGA is the only way left (even I don like them as I got very bad experience with them on frequencies around 1GHz)

Comment: For the FIFO try to find dualport RAM it is more expensive but you will not need to handle conflicts which could lead to flickering or sync loss. Hope it is clear what I have in mind if not comment me and I will try to draw a block diagram ...

Comment: Thank you so mutch for your help, and your time. I don't know yet if I'll be able to create it, but I'll work hard. 
You alredy spent a lot from your time to help me, and I really aprecheate it, but if you could draw me a diagram I'd be so happy.
ie: The image would be 3840*1080, or 1920*2160 depending on the 3D formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HDMI specification](http://www.microprocessor.org/HDMISpecification13a.pdf) at page 56  the transfer/interconnection looks like this:

[image: HDMI]

I would start with interleaved left/right format where even pixels are left and odd pixels are right because there is high chance that it does not need any **FIFO**. If you want standard left/right then you need single line **FIFO** for each channel and for up/down full image **FIFO**. In case variable clock is supported by your HW then this **simplified example** should work:

[image: no FIFOs]

You need to add H/V sync decoder from  `Channel0` to reset the binary counter. Binary counter counts which data address is being processed. The single data-line to the AND gates should be `D1` half of the input clock but not entirely you need to toggle between `D0` and `D1` depends in the timing of data processed (for pixels it would be `D1` and for other data it would be `D0`) that is the variable clock I mentioned before. The comparator just compares the address against predefined constants (like half of line for non interleaved left/right format or detect even odd for interleaved format but both must take +/- other data offsets) beware the transfer is on `bits` not `Bytes` so the address will be multiplied by number of bits per data chunk ... The gates just toggle clock between left and right part. **LATCHES** make sure output signal will be not mixed and also boost the signal.

I would start with oscilloscope measurements of the channels so you can see how the data is transfered and then experiment-ate. If you use **FPGA** then you do not need to make any changes to the board while ecxperimentating with configurations as the circuit will be solely inside **FPGA**.

If variable clock is not supported then you need to use **FIFO** and or **RAM** to store the full line/image and then send the appropriate parts to their connectors. For that you most likely need full decoding capability so use the SIL9134 + SIL9135. Halving resolution will introduce timing problems because you will need more time to send half speed half frame then the full speed full frame (the auxiliary and sync data is copied not halved). If the sending has big enough gaps you could fit the missing time there but again not all HW can support it losing sync/flickering/etc. In such case you could change the resolution to a bit smaller (after halving) to fit in the send time ... or enlarge thi full resolution input (in x axis).

Good luck with your quest.